# How to check for vertex matches and replace the repeat index on the edge?

Tags: python, numpy, triangulation, vertex

After developing code for Delaunay triangulation I made a list of node coordinates and found that there are a few numbers of duplicate nodes.

So I avoid duplicate nodes:

```
distort = tri.Triangulation(mesh_x, mesh_y) #triangulation

#making list of nodes coordinates
data = np.array([mesh_x, mesh_y])
data = np.transpose(data)

#sorting avoids duplicated nodes
unique_data = np.unique(data, axis = 0)
```

Now I have a problem with edges that connect the nodes. After removing the duplicate nodes, the edges are reallocated and instead of a smooth grid I got something like this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV6Id.jpg)

How can I check for vertex matches and replace the repeat index on the edge and get a smooth grid? (like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW1yW.png))

Comment: To me the grid images are only confusing, it would be easier to see a "minimal working example" where you prepare a mini mesh, print it to the screen, explain which nodes you would like to remove and which get removed, although you would like them to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you remove a node you need to subtract one to all the indices of triangles vertices bigger of the removed node index.